# PHP-FPM's chroot and chdir directory

Tags: php-fpm, chroot

I am setting up php-fpm with chrooting enabled. Now I see that there are two options, and I want to know what the exact difference is.

The setup has:

```
chroot = /var/www/domains/domain.tld/
; Chdir to this directory at the start. This value must be an absolute path.
; Default Value: current directory or / when chroot
chdir = /docroot/
```

Why are there two different locations here, and which path is php allowed to access. Can the php website access `/var/www/domains/domain.tld/`, or can it only access files withing the `docroot` directory.

===

Maybe there is some concrete advice for me. I want to have a setup like this:

webroot location: `/var/www/`

```
domain.com/
 |---conf/
 |    |--nginx.conf
 |    |--php-fpm.conf
 |
 |---ssl/
 |---logs/
 |---session/
 |---domains/
       |---www/
       |---app/
       |---dev/
```

Now here the php-fpm settings would be:

```
chroot = /var/www/domain.com/
chdir  = /domains/www
```

Now the main question here is, will the application located in the `www` subdomain be able to access the files in `dev` or `app`. Or even the files located in session, which is the session save path, or the other folders such as ssl and logs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Chroot sets the 'root' directory - you cannot navigate above the root directory.
- Chdir simply changes the starting directory - it is still possible to navigate to other directories (including those above this).

  - If you don't specify a chroot path, then the 'real' root applies - and you specify an absolute chdir.
  - If you do specify a chroot path, then you specify a path relative to the chroot'd path (which redefines the root directory).

The settings you have proposed seem quite fine.

- The starting path would be the chroot path + the chdir path
- The app will be able to access all files under the chroot path (unless there are other restrictions - e.g. php_openbasedir, permissions, etc) in place.

As a side note - your php-application will also have access to your nginx.conf and php-fpm.conf based on the document structure you have shown - which seems like something you may want to change (at least making the files read-only to that user).

Comment: I will make sure those files are safe. By the way, is there a difference between this method of chrooting and just setting the php_openbasedir ?

Comment: Yes - chroot applies at the operating system level and is much harder to bypass. open_basedir is specific to PHP, and needs to be checked in every function so exploits are more common (e.g. by running external scripts with shell_exec). There is an interesting [security note](http://www.php.net/security-note.php) on PHP's site on this matter. That is not to say that open_basedir is useless if you are using chroot - in any circumstance where something occurs outside your script, it may be handy to define a different open_basedir than your chroot path. Chroot also may offer better performance.