# Apache: "File Not Found" after setting up php-fpm chroot

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm

I'm struggling with the final step in implementing a chroot on php-fpm with Apache 2.4 running on CentOS 7.

I've [successfully setup](https://serverfault.com/questions/732959/chroot-php-fpm-process-to-users-home) and [tested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265765/apache-php-fpm-chroot-results-file-not-found-error) the php-fpm connection without the chroot. But as soon as I add the chroot directive into my conf file in /etc/php-fpm.d/file.conf, I get a "File Not Found" [as many other people have experienced](https://serverfault.com/questions/503150/apache-php-fpm-chroot-results-file-not-found-error).

**Here's my php-fpm conf file:**

```
[site1.com]
user = user1
group = user1
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/site1.com.sock
listen.owner = user1
listen.group = user1
php_admin_value[disable_functions] = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system
php_admin_flag[allow_url_fopen] = on
php_admin_value[short_open_tag] = On
php_admin_value[doc_root] = /
php_admin_value[error_log] = /logs/php-errors
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
chroot = /home/www/site1.com
chdir = /www
catch_workers_output = yes
```

As you can see, after I set the chroot, I changed the `chdir` directive so that it is relative to the PHP root. (The system path would be `/home/www/site1.com/www`, and that's what `chdir` was set to before enabling the `chroot` directive).

**Here's my relevant http.d/site1.conf file:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@my-host.com
        ServerName site1.com
        ServerAlias www.site1.com
        DocumentRoot /home/www/site1.com/www
        <Directory "/home/www/site1.com/www">
                Options Includes FollowSymLinks
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
ErrorLog /home/www/site1.com/logs/errors
CustomLog /home/www/site1.com/logs/access_log common
        <FilesMatch "\.php$">
                SetHandler "proxy:unix:///var/run/php-fpm/site1.com.sock|fcgi://site1.com"
        </FilesMatch>
LogLevel trace3
</VirtualHost>
```

I've turned up the LogLevel in my httpd.d/site.conf file, and here's some of that interesting output:

```
  [Mon Nov 02 10:42:52.665284 2015] [proxy:trace2] [pid 14286] proxy_util.c(2007): [client 74.221.189.99:16486] *: found reverse proxy worker for unix:///var/run/php-fpm/site1.com.sock|fcgi://site1.com/home/www/site1.com/www/index.php
    [Mon Nov 02 10:42:52.665292 2015] [proxy:trace2] [pid 14286] proxy_util.c(2041): [client 74.221.189.99:16486] *: rewrite of url due to UDS(/var/run/php-fpm/site1.com.sock): fcgi://site1.com/home/www/site1.com/www/index.php (proxy:fcgi://site1.com/home/www/site1.com/www/index.php)
    [Mon Nov 02 10:42:52.665295 2015] [proxy:debug] [pid 14286] mod_proxy.c(1117): [client 74.221.189.99:16486] AH01143: Running scheme unix handler (attempt 0)
    [Mon Nov 02 10:42:52.665300 2015] [proxy_ajp:debug] [pid 14286] mod_proxy_ajp.c(713): [client 74.221.189.99:16486] AH00894: declining URL fcgi://site1.com/home/www/site1.com/www/index.php
    [Mon Nov 02 10:42:52.665304 2015] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 14286] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(948): [client 74.221.189.99:16486] AH01076: url: fcgi://site1.com/home/www/site1.com/www/index.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
    [Mon Nov 02 10:42:52.665307 2015] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 14286] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(955): [client 74.221.189.99:16486] AH01078: serving URL fcgi://site1.com/home/www/site1.com/www/index.php
    [Mon Nov 02 10:42:52.665311 2015] [proxy:debug] [pid 14286] proxy_util.c(2200): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (*)
    [Mon Nov 02 10:42:52.665316 2015] [proxy:debug] [pid 14286] proxy_util.c(2253): [client 74.221.189.99:16486] AH00944: connecting fcgi://site1.com/home/www/site1.com/www/index.php to site1.com:8000
    [Mon Nov 02 10:42:52.665320 2015] [proxy:debug] [pid 14286] proxy_util.c(2286): [client 74.221.189.99:16486] AH02545: fcgi: has determined UDS as /var/run/php-fpm/site1.com.sock
    [Mon Nov 02 10:42:52.665420 2015] [proxy:debug] [pid 14286] proxy_util.c(2419): [client 74.221.189.99:16486] AH00947: connected /home/www/site1.com/www/index.php to httpd-UDS:0
    [Mon Nov 02 10:42:52.668135 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 14286] [client 74.221.189.99:16486] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
    [Mon Nov 02 10:42:52.668179 2015] [proxy_fcgi:trace1] [pid 14286] util_script.c(599): [client 74.221.189.99:16486] Status line from script 'index.php': 404 Not Found
    [Mon Nov 02 10:42:52.668237 2015] [http:trace3] [pid 14286] http_filters.c(992): [client 74.221.189.99:16486] Response sent with status 404
    [Mon Nov 02 10:42:52.668284 2015] [proxy:debug] [pid 14286] proxy_util.c(2215): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (*)
```

**Nothing is showing up in the php error log file.**

So, after all this,

- Why am I still getting a "File not found" error message?
- Better yet, how do I fix it, or at the very least, how do I better troubleshoot my issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is resolved. There were two issues with my above code.

### Issue #1 - Only Apache 2.4.10 and above can support sockets

The default version of Apache that comes in the base CentOS repositories (**Apache 2.4.6**) only support TCP ports. The above code is therefore incorrect, and the `listen` directive in the php-fpm config file needed to be changed to something like this:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9001
```

I also made the appropriate change in my http.d conf file, but in addition, I also switched to using the `ProxyPassMatch` directive instead of using the `FilesMatch` directive. So my code then became:

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php)$" "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001/site1.com"
```

**Note that this code is still wrong... see below**

Moving on...

### Issue #2 - Relevant Paths

The path in the `ProxyPassMatch` directive (or, in the case of my older code using the `FilesMatch` directive) inside my http.d conf file becomes relative **to the chroot**. It is not relative to the www document root (if different).

So my code in my http.d conf file became:

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php)$" "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001/www/$1"
```

And voila! I have a php-fpm chroot.

Comment: [I've asked a similar question](http://serverfault.com/questions/768406/apache-service-not-available-after-setting-up-php-fpm-chroot), and if you have any input on that I would be interested - thanks!

Comment: What version of Apache are you using? The `/$1` at the end causes `503` errors in my setup which uses version 2.4.25. If you remove this bit, it works.

Comment: Point #1 is not true, or at least isn't now. Unix sockets work fine with the stock Apache 2.4.6 packages, Red Hat apparently back ported the support.

Answer (score 4):

php-fpm has a bug with chroot and path.

for example with index.php in www

```
chroot = /home/www/site1.com
chdir = /www
```

with this config php-fpm write this path :

```
/home/www/site1.com/home/www/site1.com/www
```

one solution is to create a symbolic link
in shell :

```
cd /home/www/site1.com
mkdir -p home/www
cd home/www
ln -s /home/www/site1.com site1.com
```

but it is not clean.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55322

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62279

Comment: I've actually read that elsewhere - you're absolutely right. Unfortunately, this particular answer didn't fix my particular need. To be fair, I didn't specify I had already tried that. Anyway, my issue is fixed, and I'll be following up shortly with my own detailed answer on a couple of different errors in my above code.

Comment: Although this answer points to a useful solution, I consider it important to note that the php-fpm behaviour in question is not a bug but actually done that way by design.  The php-fpm worker process is started inside the `chroot` which makes it restrained to that environment and this is desired.

Answer (score 4):

Some people might receive this error because of 2 things.

- Wrong relative paths in php.ini
  In case you specify open_basedir, doc_root, user_dir, session.save_path, upload_tmp_dir (and others) in your PHP-FPM.conf, then these paths must be relative to chroot.
  For example:

> chroot = /var/www
>  php_admin_value[doc_root] = /htdocs
>  ;All
>   paths must be relative to chroot since after chrooting PHP does not
>   know about the absolute path

- cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1 in php.ini
  TL;DR just change it to 0.
  For some reasons this value affects your PHP-FPM even though this parameter is ment to be for CGI only.
  You should read more about this parameter since it may break other things too, more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.cgi.fix-pathinfo)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have SElinux enabled? getenforce should be able to tell you this. If that's the case, setenforce 0 would disable it and then you'd need to edit /etc/sysconfig/selinux and set SELINUX to disabled so it's persistent after rebooting.

Comment: Nope, SElinux is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of strugling with php-fpm and chroot, I managed to fix PHP-FPM with chroot, under Apache based on [this answer](https://%20https://serverfault.com/a/854735/105464)

1. Added these values in `/etc/php/8.2/fpm/pool.d/my-pool-conf.conf`

   ```
   chroot = /home/my-user-home-dir
   chdir = /public_html
   php_admin_value[doc_root] = /public_html
   php_admin_value[open_base_dir] = /public_html:/tmp
   php_admin_value[doc_root] = /public_html
   ```
2. In `/etc/php/8.2/fpm/php.ini` I changed this:

   ```
   cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
   ```

I found several answers which advised to change the Apache directive `SetHandler` with `ProxyPassMatch`, but at the moment it does not make a difference, both seem to be working